# Window remembers selected language

Tags: window, language-support, localization

Is there any way to remember selected language for particular window?

For example:
 I typed text with language #1, then switch to another window - typed text with language #2, and then switched back to to first window and my language automatically switched back to language #1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming Ubuntu 14.04: System Settings -> Text Entry (under Personal) -> select "Allow different sources for each window"